# Stream socket receiving only particular number of data how to get the full data

Tags: sockets

I am using the socket to connect the two server by this connection the data transfer between these

The process working fine for limited number of bytes result but for more number of data its only receive 8192 bytes. it working fine on the localhost but in the live server it gives the problem

Anyone have idea please share it here

i am using the below code

```
$ip="********";     //Set the TCP IP Address to connect too
$port="8088";        //Set the TCP PORT to connect too
$command="hi";       //Command to run
$req['path'] = $path;
$post = json_encode($req);
//Connect to Server
$socket = stream_socket_client("tls://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if($socket) {
 //Start SSL
     // stream_set_timeout($socket, 2);
 stream_set_blocking ($socket, true);
 stream_socket_enable_crypto ($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT);
 stream_set_blocking ($socket, false);
  // stream_set_read_buffer($socket, 0);

 //Send a command
 fwrite($socket, $post);


 $buf = null;
 //Receive response from server. Loop until the response is finished
 while (!feof($socket)) {
  $buf .= fread($socket, 229653);
 } 

 // sleep(10);
 //close connection
 fclose($socket);
 if($path=="get_activity_report")
 {
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r(strlen($buf)); exit;
 }
 //echo our command response
 return json_decode($buf);
}
```

Comment: Working as designed. Nowhere in the API does it guarantee to  fill an arbitrary sized buffer.

Comment: Okay. but in the localhost it working fine the problem only in live server, so in localhost how is it possible. so any configuration needed on server

Comment: Localhost has a much larger path MTU. You got lucky. In TCP you have to read in a loop until you get everything you need.